# Using ReactJs to fetch data from an API but getting completely blank page with no errors

Tags: reactjs

Guys Kindly i need your help. I am trying to fetch data from an Api and display it in the dom. I can see the data in the console but when i try to return data it shows a blank page and no errors. Below is my code.

**App.js file**

```
import React from "react";  
import "./App.css";    
import Movieapp from "./Movieapp";    

class App extends React.Component {    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {    
      title: [],    
      date: [],    
      image: []    
    };
 }


  componentDidMount() {    
    fetch(`https://yts.mx/api/v2/list_movies.json?quality=3D`)    
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {    
        console.log(data.data);    
        this.setState = {    
          title: data.data.movies[0].title,   
          date: data.data.movies[0].date_uploaded,    
          image: data.data.movies[0].background_image 
        };    
      });    
  }

  render() {    
    return (   
      <div className="App">    
        <Movieapp    
          title={this.state.title}    
          date={this.state.date}    
          image={this.state.image}    
        />

      </div>    
    );    
  }    
}


export default App;
```

**Movieapp.js file**

```
import React from "react";

const Movieapp = props => {    
  return (    
    <div>    
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>    
      <h1>{props.date}</h1>    
      <div>{props.image}</div>    
    </div>    
  );

};


export default Movieapp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.setState is a function, not a property. You have to use it properly:

```
this.setState({
     title: data.data.movies[0].title,    
     date: data.data.movies[0].date_uploaded,   
     image: data.data.movies[0].background_image  
});
```

Also, even though I guess you are just trying things our, there are few things to be aware of:

- movies[0] can be undefined
- You are getting multiple movies but showing only one. It's probably better to just save the whole data array in the state and iterate over the results in the render method

Comment: Added some important info.